# Set cookie ( Popup )

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, modal-dialog

i tried to set cookie in this code, but it dosen't work, someone who can help me?

i want to set a cookie in this popup modal, i want to show it only ones or the cookie can expire in some weeks, dosent mather. Thanks

```
    $(function() {
        function launch() {
             $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }

        $('#try-1').ready(function(e) {

            $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, preventScroll: true, onLoad: function() {
            $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }});

            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

to set a cookie using jQuery u have to do this:

`$.cookie("myCookie", <cookieValue>, {
   expires : <days>,
   path    : '/',
   domain  : '<your domain>',
   secure  : false  //Need SSL?
});`

and to get a cookie:

`$.cookie("test");`

But you can use Web Storage instead of cookies. To set data:

`localStorage.setItem("<propname>", "<value>");`

To get data:

`localStorage.getItem("<propname>");`

See more at [W3Schools webstorage example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)